# Sufficient condition for convergence in mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

I want to prove that if $\xi_n$ is sequence of non-negative random variables, $\xi_n\xrightarrow {a.e.}\xi$ and $\mathbb{E}\xi_n^p \to \mathbb{E}\xi^p $ than $$\mathbb{E}|\xi_n-\xi|^p\to0 \text{ (i.e. }\xi_n\xrightarrow {L^p}\xi)$$
I don't know where to start. I would be very grateful for help!

Comment: You are actually asking for **strong convergence** in $L^p$.

Comment: @UserA Seems to be convergence in mean, right?

Comment: Convergence in mean is usually only used for the case $p=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Brezis-Lieb lemma and goes as follows: suppose that $p>1$.

- Prove first that there is a constant $C$ depending on $p$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ you have $$\left||a+b|^p-|a|^p-|b|^p \right|\leq C\left(|a|^{p-1}|b|+|a||b|^{p-1} \right).$$
- Assume in addition that $\|\xi_n\|_{L^p}\leq M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$ and prove that
  $$\mathbb{E}\left[|\xi_n|^p-|\xi_n-\xi|^p\right]\to \mathbb{E}[|\xi|].$$
- Now remove the above assumption, and conclude.

For the case $p=1$.

- Prove that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ you have
  $$||a+b|-|a|-|b||\leq 2|b|.$$
- Assume in addition that $\|\xi_n\|_{L^1}\leq M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$ and prove that
  $$\mathbb{E}\left[|\xi_n|-|\xi_n-\xi|\right]\to \mathbb{E}[|\xi|].$$
- Now remove the above assumption, and conclude.

---

Here is a way to prove the result without the Brezis-Lieb lemma. Indeed, for $p\geq 1$ we have the [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184781/prove-that-abp-leq-2p-ap-bp)
$$|a-b|^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|a|^p+|b|^p),\;\;\text{ for all }a,b\in\mathbb{R}. $$
Therefore
$$|\xi_n-\xi|^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|\xi_n|^p+|\xi|^p).$$
Also since $\xi_n \xrightarrow {a.e.} \xi$ then you clearly have that $$2^{p-1}(|\xi_n|^p+|\xi|^p)\xrightarrow {a.e.} 2^{p}|\xi|^p\in L^1\;\;\; (\text{since }\xi\in L^p),$$
and by the assumption $\mathbb{E}[|\xi_n|^p]\to \mathbb{E}[|\xi|^p]$  we have
$$ \mathbb{E}[2^{p-1}(|\xi_n|^p+|\xi|^p)]\to \mathbb{E}[2^p\,|\xi|^p]. $$
Therefore by ([a slightly stronger version of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053611/show-that-for-f-n-le-g-n-forall-n-lim-n-to-infty-int-e-g-n/2053719#2053719)) dominated convergence applied to
$$ f_n:=|\xi_n-\xi|^p, \;\;\; f:=0,\;\;\;g_n:=2^{p-1}(|\xi_n|^p+|\xi|^p),\;\;\;g:=2^p|\xi|^p,$$
you get that $\mathbb{E}[f_n]\to 0 $ as desired.

Comment: Thank you, where can I find the proof of this lemma?

Comment: For the case $p>1$ the proof of the second bullet can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brezis%E2%80%93Lieb_lemma.
I advise you to do the case $p=1$ yourself.

Comment: In the last line you say that $|\xi_n-\xi|^p\xrightarrow{a.e.}0$, could you please explain to me why this is so?

Comment: This is because $\xi_n \xrightarrow {a.e.} \xi$.

Comment: Why then was everything above this line necessary?

Comment: Yes. You cannot deduce directly that $\mathbb{E}[|\xi_n-\xi|^p]\to 0$ if $|\xi_n -\xi|^p \to 0$.

Comment: Did we do this to show the limitations of the $|\xi_n-\xi|$?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your last question.

Comment: Why cannot I deduce directly that E[|ξn−ξ|p]→0 if |ξn−ξ|p→0?
Why can't I immediately apply the Dominant Convergence Theorem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120710/discussion-between-usera-and-nick-niceday).